# how to import site-package modules?

Tags: python, package

i recently installed PyGO, and the installer automatically installed it in site-package directory. My Problem is that I don't know how to access that directory and the modules contained in it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends. if you are using a virtual environment it should be in `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`. Or `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/` if not

Comment: You should be able to import them the same way you import anything else. If you can't, you have some other problem. Maybe you're mixing up multiple Python installations; that's a common one.

Comment: I am not using virtual environment. I installed Pycharm with Python in combination.